# EasyAdmin 3 - Impersonate User in dashboard

Tags: php, symfony4, impersonation, easyadmin

I have tried to used easyAdmin3 for making an admin account quickly, but how do you make a proper impersonate user action ?

I have tried a lot of things but the best option are made custom action so this link appear in page but it's don't works properly...

Impersonate works but on only page linked in url (impersonate has stopped if page change) and User don't change in Symfony Toolbar...

My custom Action :

```
    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        $impersonate = Action::new('impersonate', 'Impersonate')
            ->linkToRoute('web_account_index', function (User $entity) {
               return [
                    'id' => $entity->getId(),
                   '?_switch_user' => $entity->getEmail()
               ];
            })
        ;
        return parent::configureActions($actions)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $impersonate)
            ;
    }
```

Result :
[Dashboard link for each user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdpk8.png)

After click on impersonate, I have this url :

```
https://blog-community.wip/account/7?eaContext=37a8719&?_switch_user=user7@user.com
```

Content are ok (page account for user 7) but Symfony Profiler show User admin instead of impersonated User :

[Symfony profiler user logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcpbB.png)

Change page exit impersonate...

Real Symfony impersonate keep impersonation even if page changes because profiler user logged are different [Symfony profiler user logged with impersonate directly in url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKoRO.png)

documentation not refer this functionality, EasyAdmin's Github issues too ans this website too.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

I am not a big fan of using hardcoded rules, so injected the UrlGenerator to my CrudController:

```php
$impersonate = Action::new('impersonate', 'Impersonate')
    ->linkToUrl(function (User $user): string {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(
            Routes::DASHBOARD,
            ['_switch_user' => $user->getEmail()],
            UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
        );
    });
```

Comment: In my oppinion best answer for EasyAdminBundle v3.2.0 and higher.

Answer (score 2):

For EasyAdmin 3.2.x the prior solution stopped working. This is working for me now:

```
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{
    $impersonate = Action::new('impersonate', false, 'fa fa-fw fa-user-lock')
        //changed from linkToRoute to linkToUrl. note that linkToUrl has only one parameter.
        //"admin/.. can be adjusted to another URL"
        ->linkToUrl(function (User $entity) {
            return 'admin/?_switch_user='.$entity->getUsername();
        })
    ;

    $actions = parent::configureActions($actions);
    $actions->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $impersonate);

    return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved !

EasyAdmin add automatically some parameters in url so "?" are already here but I added it too in my custom action...

Example :

```
https://blog-community.wip/account/7?eaContext=37a8719&?_switch_user=user7@user.com
```

```
    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        $impersonate = Action::new('impersonate', 'Impersonate')
            ->linkToRoute('web_account_index', function (User $entity) {
               return [
                    'id' => $entity->getId(),
                   '_switch_user' => $entity->getEmail() 
                   // removed ? before _switch_user
               ];
            })
        ;
        return parent::configureActions($actions)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $impersonate)
            ;
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you put a `?` in there in the first place?

Comment: I forgot that Symfony adds ```?``` automatically if the parameter is not expected in the route, I wanted to build the url manually but it's stupid ^^'

Comment: Does not work anymore since EasyAdminBundle v3.2.0.